# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 5: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, web.py

my web app ran very well before, but days ago a problem came, now i can start my web app, but when i browse my site from local(127.0.0.1) or remote(192.168.xxx.xxx)(only simply open the homepage, no inputs from mouse and keyboard), crashs the webapp like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/project/web/application.py", line 242, in process
  return self.handle()
File "/path/to/project/web/application.py", line 233, in handle
  return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
File "/path/to/project/web/application.py", line 415, in _delegate
  return handle_class(cls)
File "/path/to/project/web/application.py", line 390, in handle_class
  return tocall(*args)
File "./my_web_app.py", line 40, in GET
  simplejson.dumps(manus))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 286, in dumps
  return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 226, in encode
  chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 296, in iterencode
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 5: invalid continuation byte
192.168.xxx.xxx:2131 - - [27/Nov/2013 16:51:09] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error
192.168.xxx.xxx:2131 - - [27/Nov/2013 16:51:09] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 404 Not Found
192.168.xxx.xxx:2131 - - [27/Nov/2013 16:51:09] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 404 Not Found
```

and I dont think there is some thing wrong with my codes, because my codes run very well in my computer, the error appears only when it runs on the server. The directory "web" is a link to "web.py-0.34/web", it is not my codes.

my codes are simple:

```
urls = (
    '/', 'find_alternate',
    '/find_alternates', 'find_alternate',
    '/show_detail/(.+)', 'show_detail'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())
class find_alternate:
    def GET(self):
        brands = [b.brandName for b in Brand.q.all()]
        brands.sort()
        manus = [oe.brandName for oe in OeNumber.q.group_by(OeNumber.brandName)]
        manus.sort()
        return render.find_alternates_main(simplejson.dumps(brands), simplejson.dumps(manus))
"""
some more functions, but not relevant
"""
render = web.template.render('/path/to/templates/')
web.template.Template.globals['str'] = str
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

my CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `brandNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brandName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brandNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

My problem is now hwo to convert character Ë from Unicode to utf-8, so that jsonsimple can parse it. In wiki I found this:

```
Unicode: U+00CB
UTF-8: C3(hex) 8B(hex)
```

How I soluted:
added the following lines to my.cnf:

```
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

converted database to utf-8:

```
ALTER DATABASE `db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: "I dont think there is something wrong" isn't really enough. Post the significant piece of code, please.

Comment: Obviously, there's something wrong with either your code, or your web server config, or the way you're accessing it. And since you haven't given us any information about any of the three, there's no way anyone can possibly help you. Except to give you the general hint that you're probably sending non-UTF-8 data (e.g., Latin-1 or Windows CP1252) for some reason and your code or web.py is trying to interpret it as UTF-8 for some reason. If you haven't read [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), now might be a good time.

Comment: sry, i didn't finish my words and missclicked "post"

Comment: If your code nothing wrong, then may be your data wrong?

Comment: how could I test that? I have printed brands and manus in hex for every byte, there is no "0xcb".

Comment: what is your settings.py?  what character set is your database configured to use?  i guess your database has entries added in one character set, but your application is expecting them to be in utf8.  what did you use to add data to your database?

Comment: I think I found the problem, the database in server is a little defferent with my local one, there is word CITROËN(in variable manus) with character Ë(0xcb) in server database, some one else has inserted it, I can not remove it because it is a brand name of car producer, how can my app parse this character?
I will post my CREATE TABLE later.

Comment: just because of this word "CITROËN", I read this word from server db and print it like this, behind is detection of chardet.py:
CITRO薔 - 43:49:54:52:4f:cb:4e (utf-8). 
But this word from my local db looks like:
CITROËN - 43:49:54:52:4f:c3:8b:4e (SHIFT_JIS). 
Is 0xcb not utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

`u'\xcb'` is an unicode representation of `'\xc3\x8b'`,

```
>>> u'CITRO\xcbN'.encode('utf-8')
'CITRO\xc3\x8bN'
```

and its `latin-1` encoding:

```
>>> u'CITRO\xcbN'.encode('latin-1')
'CITRO\xcbN'
```

So your server db seems to be not utf-8 encoded.

I think best solution would be to check your server tables encoding, and if it is not `utf8`, migrate to `utf8`. If tables are in utf8, you have to fix data, as data is not.

Alternatively, you can infer encoding from db settings and pass to simplejson:

```
simplejson.dumps(manus, encoding=encoding)
```

But this approach will lead to difference between server and dev and errors in future.

Comment: I have converted the data in database in server to utf-8 and dumped the table with mysqldump, then checked with hexdump, it is really utf-8, same as my local server, but met another problem, after python app read the data, the data have been changed to non-utf-8. Is the connection charset problem? I found no solution in google.

Comment: and something more, the variable character_set_database in mysql server(5.5.34) is always latin1, the others have been changed to utf8 by me in file my.conf. I tried to set this variable in my.conf, but mysqld failed to start.

Comment: @Cricket I propose you to start a brand new thread on this issue (this particular one seems to be resolved, no?). I'm sorry, but right now am a little bit busy to deep in your mysql issue, and with new thread I hope someone will help you faster than me.

Comment: Thanks, I also wanted to start a new plan, but I tried to wait the answer for the last time. And luckly I found the solution which I will post it later.